# What is architecture diagram for web application?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, class-diagram

I am working on web application and I have to submit it's high level design/architecture diagram.Can anybody tell me what exactly architecture diagram is?

PS: I have to draw class diagram seperately.

Comment: A cursory Google search reveals useful examples of what architecture diagrams look like: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+application+architecture+diagram

Comment: It is a diagram of the architecture [of the web application] .. exactly *what* that entails, and to what extent, varies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Architecture diagrams is about technology going to be used, and communication between them. Like, I have web application, I am doing this diagram.

1. Client(Android/IOS(java/objective C, or some framework like, trigger io or titanium)).
2. Client(Browser app(some technologies, like css3, lesscss, jquery, or angular js)
3. Web server(we have 2 servers, for example front-end server like ngnix, and back-end server like node.js or netty)
4. Database server (we use 2 databases for example, mysql and couch db) I also write for which reason what you are using.

Then you free to draw dependency between this things, to explain communication and understanding of stack being used for your application

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding from my experience, architecture for web or windows applications are not different.
Let me share a gap in architecture diagram preparation that I have seen in my practice (also there in the referred book below sl no. 3)
Let me share one improvement that should be useful. Most architecture diagrams are a form of component and connector diagrams (blocks connected by lines or arrows). The ignored part of preparing this diagram is failing to articulate what the connector (or arrow) stands.  For example, if there is an arrow from component A to component B [two components connected by arrow connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3tzM.png), what the connector means cannot be quite clear unless key or legend is provided. That is an area for improvement I have seen. For example, such a connector without key/legend can be interpreted in any of the following ways & can mislead the understanding:
(a) A dependent on B (b) Data flows from A to B (c) A sends message to B
(d) A instantiates B (e) A calls B (f) A is a subtype of B. etc.

Following are good reference of architecture diagrams options and references I know of:

1. 4+1 View of rational Unified Process (RUP). This is still good though not referred so much lately. However the development view (or component view) and deployment view are two diagrams one should prepare. Books are also available. [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Egregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf)
2. C4 model of visualizing architecture is another good reference
   https://c4model.com/
3. Following is a good book by many greats of software can be useful. Documenting Software Architectures: Views and Beyond by by Paul Clements (Author), Felix Bachmann (Author), Len Bass (Author), David Garlan (Author), James Ivers (Author), Reed Little (Author), Paulo Merson (Author), Robert Nord (Author), Judith Stafford (Author) is an excellent book to understand best way to prepare architecture.
   https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=30386
4. Another very good book is, Fundamentals of Software Architecture by Neal & Robert Martin, O'Reilly https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_Software_Architecture/_pNdwgEACAAJ?hl=en
   The video course with O'Reilly online is really excellent (9 Hrs+)
   https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/software-architecture-fundamentals/9781491998991/

I have referred some architecture books/IEEE papers but still to find a good simple reference and ready to use reference/book. However the famous layered form of diagram is quite popular. Please note to include technology and tools used in different components in an architecture diagram in component diagram.
Hope this helps. I am available at LinkedIn, should you feel like, I can help more.